# Shared depth buffer using multiple renders?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using the THREE.WebGLRenderer() and the THREE.CSS3DRenderer() together and it works well, but it appears like they don't share the same depth buffer. The CSS always shows over the regular renderer. Is there any way to have the two renderers respect on another?

```
scene=new THREE.Scene();                                                                         
scene2=new THREE.Scene();                                                                       
renderer=new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });                                           
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);                                        
renderer2=new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);                                     
container.appendChild(renderer2.domElement);    

render() {
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
    renderer2.render(scene,camera);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No unfortunately not. WebGL and CSS are technically two different things and completely independent. Hence, it's not possible to share a common depth buffer for both `THREE.WebGLRenderer` and `THREE.CSS3DRenderer`.

`three.js R106`